# How to tell the tableviewcell class label name in visual format constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

This is my code given below :

```
 NSDictionary *viewsDictionary =   NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cell.lblname);
    NSLog(@"%@",viewsDictionary);
   NSArray *constra= [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-10-[cell.lblname]-10-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    //Work through the array of constraints, applying each to the superview
    for (int i = 0; i<constra.count; i++) {
        [cell.contentView addConstraint:constra[i]];
    }
```

This is What i get

```
2015-12-14 16:23:34.846 hello[2354:102290] {
    "cell.lblname" = "<UILabel: 0x7fd6a1cb7a80; frame = (0 0; 318 40); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fd6a1cf4610>>";
}
2015-12-14 16:23:34.898 hello[2354:102290] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
cell is not a key in the views dictionary. 
|-10-[cell.lblname]-10-| 
          ^'
```

how to solve this issues help me ,i am new to visual constraints ....

Comment: what is your label's property name? is it `lblname`?

Comment: @AndréSlotta property (nonatomic ,retain) UILabel *lblname;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = {@"lblname": self.lblname};
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-10-[lblname]-10-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
[cell.contentView addConstraints:constraints];
```

Comment: super :) now i understood